# How can I post a Date to node.js / express.js?

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, date, express

I am using node.js with express as backend and I have several object which have date type properties, what happen is that when I post them to my webservices, the date got converted to string.

Is there a way (format) in which they can keep as date? without me having to property by property and doing the conversion manually?

I tried sending an ISO String, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to convert the date to time and use that when instantiating a date object on the server:

```
// client
var date = +new Date(); // or alternatively: date.getTime();

// server
var date = new Date(posted_date);
```